# Notepad++ как подсветить цветовые коды в любом файле?

Tags: color, notepad++, highlighting

Ищу решение, которое могло бы подсвечивать цветовые коды (#FF0000 ,rgb(0,255,0) и т.д.) их же значениями!
Да еще и в любом файле! Хоть .txt
Пока нашел несколько устаревших плагинов, лишь один из них работает, да и то только в css и html файлах.
Я работаю с .cs файлами иногда с .cfg .json и даже в текстовых файлах могут быть коды цветов.
Минимум который решил бы мою проблему, это подсветка хотя бы HEX (#eeffaa) в любом файле который открыт в npp.